# Understanding browser window height (for jQuery use)

Tags: jquery

When using:

```
var size = $(window).height();
```

Firefox console shows me: 594

but in here: http://whatsmy.browsersize.com/

I can see that my browser height is: Browser window height: 861

Which I should take for granted or what I do not understand in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a fast test to be sure. Print screen + measured in photoshop. Got pixel perfect matched values with latest versions of **Firefox, Chrome and Safari in Mac OS X Mountain Lion** with `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()`. `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()` shows the browsers "workarea" without scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is because of the offset of your console. Is it fixed on the bottom of your browser? If yes: pop it out and try again.

You just can take window.innerHeight, it's your height for the visible area in your browser.

The size on browsersize.com is right.

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).height()` returns browser window's workarea height.

You can read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/height/).